# Let $\mathfrak{p},\mathfrak{q}$ be prime ideals of the ring $R$ s.t. $\mathfrak{p}+\mathfrak{q}\neq 1$. Must $\mathfrak{p}+\mathfrak{q}$ be prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

A previous question asked this in full generality, without the condition that $\mathfrak{p}+\mathfrak{q}\neq 1$; however, I was wondering if the statement is false only in that particular edge case, or if there are any examples where this is not true at all.

The difficulty in proving this statement comes from factoring out some $xy\in\mathfrak{p}+\mathfrak{q}$ in a way that uses the primality of the ideals $\mathfrak{p}$ and $\mathfrak{q}$. Because of this, I suspect that the statement may be false. Unfortunately, most of my experience in ring theory is working with UFDs and polynomial rings, and I can't seem to find any counterexamples.

If this statement is not true over all rings, what is the largest class of rings on which this statement holds? Must it hold over all UFDs?

Comment: It will be hard to find counterexamples in a PID, since prime ideals are comaximal in any Dedekind domain.

Comment: That follows from the unique factorization criterion on Dedekind domains, doesn't it?

Comment: You can say it follows from that property of a Dedekind domain, yet it may be easier to derive it from the fact that every non-zero prime ideal is maximal in  a Dedekind domain (that is it has Krull dimension one). (In combination with the fact that every ideal is contained in a maximal ideal.)

Comment: You asked for the intersection of two irreducible varieties to be irreducible again. This is of course false.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take $R = \mathbb{Z}[X]$. Let $p$ be a prime. Then $X^2+p$ is irreducible, and  $(X^2+p)$ is prime. The ideal $(p)$ is also prime. The ideals are not co-prime. The ideal $(X^2+p) + (p)$ is not prime, as it contains $X \cdot X$ yet not $X$.

Note that this domain has Krull dimension $2$, as has the example in the other answer.  And, one needs Krull dimension at least $2$ for a domain to have this property. Since in a domain with Krull dimension $1$, such as a PID, all non-zero prime ideals are pairwise co-prime.

Yet, both examples are still UFDs.

Answer (score 6):

Well, what's a next-worst scenario from a PID? Polynomial ring in two variables, i.e, for a field $k$,  $k[X,Y]$, gives you an immediate counter-example. Let $k=\mathbb{R}$, $\mathfrak{p}=(X^2+Y^2)$, and $\mathfrak{q}=(X)$. Then $\mathfrak{p+q}=(X^2+Y^2,X)=(X,Y^2)$, which of course isn't prime.

Comment: @user26857, Well I did say $k=\mathbb{R}$, but if you want $k$ to be $\mathbb{C}$, just take $X^2+Y^2-1$.

Comment: No need to change the polynomial whenever change the field: $\mathfrak p=(X+Y^2)$ works over any field.